# Using jQuery for slider, first works but second doesn't. Dynamic Elements Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a jQuery slider that I am trying to repeat on the page nearly 20 times. If I have just one of the sliders, it works great! However, I need help figuring out what is wrong with it that makes it break if there are more more the initial set of sliders. If I can create solve this problem dynamically that would be optimal, so that an indefinite number of sliders can be added to the page. Code below:

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Call plugin if you put in head if not not require DOMContentLoaded
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    new boxSlider(document.querySelector('#slide-one'),{
        delay: '1000', // ms
        effect: 'ease-in-out'
    });

    new boxSlider(document.querySelector('#slide-two'),{
        delay: '2000', // ms
        effect: 'ease'
    });

    new boxSlider(document.querySelector('#slide-three'),{
        delay: '500', // ms
        effect: 'linear'
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="row1mini">
    <section id="slide-one" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://ep.yimg.com/ay/stylinonline/superman-vintage-logo-3-4-raglan-t-shirt-sheer-4.jpg" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="https://s7.jcrew.com/is/image/jcrew/78151_WW0699?$pdp_fs418$" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://www.royalrobbins.co.uk/images/coolmesh-baja-l-s-shirt-soapstone-p130-119_zoom.jpg" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </article>
        <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
    <section id="slide-two" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.patagonia.com/tsimages/55005_579.fpx?wid=1000&hei=1000&ftr=8&effect=dropshadow,0x000000,10,8,120,8&cvt=jpeg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.peterglenn.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_1000x1000/product_images_new/70288_13_BRT_BLUE_LG.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.oldnavy.com/products/res/thumbimg/fleece-pants-for-baby-tangelo.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
      </figure>
      </article>
      <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
    <section id="slide-three" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.photo-dictionary.com/photofiles/list/2517/3301gym_shoes.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Mens'_ballroom_shoes,_Eurodance_CZ.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.dunklowbox.com/images/dunks/Reebok-Hello-Kitty-Travel-PT-20-INT-White-Red-RBK-Brass.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
      </figure>
      </article>
      <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
  </div>
```

**HERE I DUPLICATE THE ABOVE HTML, CAUSING THE SLIDER TO BREAK**

```
  <div id="row1mini">
 <section id="slide-one" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://ep.yimg.com/ay/stylinonline/superman-vintage-logo-3-4-raglan-t-shirt-sheer-4.jpg" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="https://s7.jcrew.com/is/image/jcrew/78151_WW0699?$pdp_fs418$" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://www.royalrobbins.co.uk/images/coolmesh-baja-l-s-shirt-soapstone-p130-119_zoom.jpg" alt=""/>
          <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </article>
        <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
    <section id="slide-two" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.patagonia.com/tsimages/55005_579.fpx?wid=1000&hei=1000&ftr=8&effect=dropshadow,0x000000,10,8,120,8&cvt=jpeg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.peterglenn.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_1000x1000/product_images_new/70288_13_BRT_BLUE_LG.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.oldnavy.com/products/res/thumbimg/fleece-pants-for-baby-tangelo.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
      </figure>
      </article>
      <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
    <section id="slide-three" class="slide">
      <article class="slide-inner">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.photo-dictionary.com/photofiles/list/2517/3301gym_shoes.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The Underground</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Mens'_ballroom_shoes,_Eurodance_CZ.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The city</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.dunklowbox.com/images/dunks/Reebok-Hello-Kitty-Travel-PT-20-INT-White-Red-RBK-Brass.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>The map</figcaption>
      </figure>
      </article>
      <a href="#" class="btn right" >></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn left" ><</a>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the HTML but need to change the id's of the added sliders... id's need to be unique.. you'll need to add more slider instances for each set of unique id's

Comment: What if I am going to be adding an indefinite number of sliders (depending on how many instances a user has)?

Comment: that's a bit beyond the scope of the question... the id's being the same and lack of slider instances, is the reason it's not working..making it dynamic is a whole other ball game

Comment: here's a hint tho.. document.getElementsByClassName('slide') will return an htmlcollection (array) of silder containers, that you could iterate through and create anew instance on each iteration